# Code: BadRequest Message: /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to upload file on onedrive by using **microsoft graph onedrive api**.
I am using the method for authentication
**Client credentials provider**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider

Like:

```
// /.default scope, and preconfigure your permissions on the
// app registration in Azure. An administrator must grant consent
// to those permissions beforehand.
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

// Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
// single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
var tenantId = "my-tenantid";

// Values from app registration
var clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
var clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

// https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

         HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files;[0];
                int fileSize = file.ContentLength;
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string mimeType = file.ContentType;
                Stream fileContent = file.InputStream;


     var res = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(fileName).Content
                        .Request()
                        .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileContent);
```

After executing this code then it gives an error in response.

```
Message: /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2021-12-29T05:30:08
    request-id: b51e50ea-4a62-4dc7-b8d2-b26d75268cdc
    client-request-id: b51e50ea-4a62-4dc7-b8d2-b26d75268cdc
ClientRequestId: b51e50ea-4a62-4dc7-b8d2-b26d75268cdc
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Client credential flow will generate the token on behalf the app itself, so in this scenario, users don't need to sign in first to generate the token stand for the user and then call the api. And because of the design，when you used `Me` in the graph SDK, your code/app don't know who is `Me` so it can't work. You should know the user_id first and use `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}` instead of `/Me`, in the SDK, that is `graphClient.Users["your_user_id"]` instead of `graphClient.Me`

In your scenario, there're 2 solutions, one way is using delegated authentication flow like what you said in your title, another way is get the user id before calling the graph api so that you can use `Users["id"]` but not `Me`

===================== Update=========================

I haven't finished the code yet but I found the correct solution now.

Firstly, we can upload file to one drive by [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-upload-a-new-file), you may check the screenshot if this is one drive or sharepoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id/drive/items/root:/testupload2.txt:/content
```

[image]
[image]

If it is, then the next is easy, using the code below to get an access token and send http request to calling the api:

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "your_azuread_clientid";
var clientSecret = "corresponding_client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
var token = clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext).Result.Token;
```

I know it's complex because the api is not the same as [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-updating-an-existing-file) which has SDK sample, but I think it also deserves to try if they are similar.

Comment: thanks: I have done the `GraphServiceClient` authentication and also successfully upload files but now the problem is   my uploaded files going to **sharepoint Communication site**.
But I want to upload on **onedrive** not sharepoint Communication site.
So please can you explain my point problem.