# Azure Client credentials provider throws error '/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow'

Tags: java, azure, graph

I am following Microsoft documentation in obtaining credentials for Azure Graph API.  [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#authorization-code-provider) states that an unattended application should use `client credentials provider` when making web api calls.

The [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#client-credentials-provider) in the documents for this is:

```
final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
        .clientId(clientId)
        .clientSecret(clientSecret)
        .tenantId(tenant)
        .build();

List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, clientSecretCredential);

final GraphServiceClient graphClient =
  GraphServiceClient
    .builder()
    .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
    .buildClient();

final User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
```

But I encounter an exception on the last line:

```
Error message: /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.
```

In researching this error, I came across [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/852080/how-to-fix-34me-request-is-only-valid-with-delegat.html) that explains the error further - which confuses me as to why the documentation would use what *appears to be* inappropriate example of how to consume this API. It appears to be `delegated permissions authorization code flow`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70515836/code-badrequest-message-me-request-is-only-valid-with-delegated-authenticatio) does not add any clarity.

> What is the correct way to make this call?  Or is this the result of incorrect configuration settings in
> [Azure management console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#application-permissions) for the app to use Application permissions instead of Delegated permissions?

- Azure identity = v1.3.1

Comment: If you have an automated system credential calling `/me`, what exactly is the data you're hoping to get?

Comment: @DerekGusoff - That is my question here - That is the example in the documentation and it makes no sense to me.  Why would Microsoft document use inappropriate example usage?

Comment: sometimes stuff is wrong. the person putting it together was copy/pasting some code between examples.

Comment: @DerekGusoff Thank you, I do understand the docs are wrong - that is why I am reaching out to SO to find the correct answer.  :)  I have reached out to MS, but that will take a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is wrong - Omit the last line of the example altogether.

Calls made to API using `credentials provider flow` take the form:

`graphClient.users("user-id")`

instead of:

`graphClient.me()`

To send an email using `credentials provider flow`:

```
...

graphClient.users("username@domain.com")
                .sendMail(UserSendMailParameterSet
                        .newBuilder()
                        .withMessage(message)
                        .withSaveToSentItems(saveToSentItems)
                        .build())
                .buildRequest()
                .post();
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make any sense to call `/me` with a client credential flow, because there is no `/me` there. It's just an automated credential. It doesn't have any user data to fetch.